# Trying to simplify javascript with var instead of numbers. Am I going about this all wrong?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, getelementbyid, var, modulus

I'm trying to make my FizzBuzz do calculations using modulus by variable in order to simplify the code. They are supposed to count up to 140 displaying True or False.

My previous 'if' statement looks like this (and it worked) :

```
if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0)
```

The example that I've seen looks like this:

```
if (checkDivision(iCounter, secondDivisor))
```

I've created variables for the counter, the two divisors, and the modulus checker, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Any help is appreciated because I am still very new to javascript and coding in general.

Here is my code so far:

```
    function clickAlert2() {
  var firstDivisor = 3;
  var secondDivisor = 5;
  for (var iCounter = 1; iCounter <= 140; iCounter++) {
    var checkDivision =
      iCounter % firstDivisor === 0 || iCounter % secondDivisor === 0;
    if (checkDivision(iCounter, firstDivisor)) {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
        checkDivision + ". True [3] <br>";
    } else if (checkDivision(iCounter, secondDivisor)) {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
        checkDivision + ". True [5] <br>";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
        checkDivision + ". False <br>";
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Alright, so now my only problem is that the numbers that should be divisible by five, are being displayed as divisible by three when clearly that isn't possible:

```
    function clickAlert2() {

  function checkDivision(counter) {

    var firstDivisor = 3,
      secondDivisor = 5;

    return (counter % firstDivisor === 0) || (counter % secondDivisor === 0);
  };

  for (var iCounter = 1; iCounter <= 140; iCounter++) {

    if (checkDivision(iCounter)) {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
        iCounter + ". True [3] <br>";
    } else if (checkDivision(iCounter)) {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
        iCounter + ". True [5] <br>";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
        iCounter + ". False <br>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The old code was immediately readable. Your new code is incredibly not, and it's giving you problems, so... I'd say stick with the clean code you had before.

Comment: `checkDivision` is not a function - it's the *current result* of evaluationg `iCounter % firstDivisor === 0 || iCounter % secondDivisor === 0;`

Comment: Your checkDivision variable is a Boolean, or a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can realize from your code segment you are trying to detect the numbers between 1 - 140 which are divisible by 3(`firstDivisor`) and 5(`secondDivisor`). you need loop which go through 1 -140 and a function (`checkDivision`) function which determine given number is the number divisible by 3 and 5.

```
function clickAlert2() {

  function checkDivision(counter, divisor) {

    return (counter % divisor === 0);
  };

  var firstDivisor = 3,
    secondDivisor = 5;

  for (var iCounter = 1; iCounter <= 140; iCounter++) {

    //check divsible by both divisors
    if (checkDivision(iCounter, firstDivisor) && checkDivision(iCounter, )) {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
        iCounter + ". True [" + firstDivisor + " " + secondDivisor + "] <br>";
    }

    //check divible by first divisor
    else if (checkDivision(iCounter, firstDivisor)) {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
        iCounter + ". True [" + firstDivisor + "] <br>";
    }
    //check divible by second divisor
    else if (checkDivision(iCounter, secondDivisor)) {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
        iCounter + ". True [" + secondDivisor + "] <br>";
    }
    //cannot divisible either divisors
    else {
      document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
        iCounter + ". False <br>";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this almost works! My only issue now is that the numbers that should be divisible by 5 are displaying as divisible by three...

Comment: @ScienceOfTheBurn Edited

Comment: This makes the output display almost every output as False, limiting the only true statements as divisible by both 5 and 3.

Comment: what your question? do you want to display the number which divisible by 3 or 5 OR which which divisible by 3 and 5?

Comment: I want to display the number that is divisible by 3 as true, I also want to display the number that is divisible by five as true, any other number that cannot be divisible by either of those variables needs to be displayed as false.

Answer (score 1):

Your checkDivision is a Boolean variable and not a function. So you simply pass it as the expression in the if and else if statements.

```
if(checkDivision){.....}
```

Also, for a fizzbuzz you could make a function like this.

```
function fizzbuzz(num){
  if(num % 3 === 0 && num % 5 === 0)
     return "FizzBuzz";
  else if(num % 3 === 0)
     return "Fizz";
  else if(num % 5 === 0)
     return "Buzz";
  else return "none";
}
```

Now you can compare the string returned by this function to know exactly whether it is a fizz, or Buzz, or a fizzbuzz

Comment: Alright, that seemed to work as far as getting it to count 140 times, and displaying true and false. My only question that remains is whether I can have it display the number that was divided and leave true and false to my "description"?

Comment: Since with each iteration of the loop, the number contained in the variable iCounter is the number getting divided, you can use the iCounter variable for your purpose

Comment: Also, it seems like with that solution it won't display the number that was divisible by 5, all of the true values were divided by three.

Comment: I've included a function in the answer as an example, please have a look

Comment: Yes, I had it this way before and it worked, I'm just trying to find a way to make it work using variables instead. That way I can improve it's flexibility a little bit more.

Comment: Maybe, that's the best flexibility you can provide, since 4 different outputs are possible in a fizzbuzz program

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
function clickAlert2() {
    var firstDivisor = 3;
    var secondDivisor = 5;
    var checkDivision = function (counter, divisor) {
        return counter % divisor === 0;
    };

    for (var iCounter = 1; iCounter <= 140; iCounter++) {
        if (checkDivision(iCounter, firstDivisor)) {
            document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
                iCounter + ". True [3] <br>";
        } else if (checkDivision(iCounter, secondDivisor)) {
            document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
                iCounter + ". True [5] <br>";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("ngList").innerHTML +=
                iCounter + ". False <br>";
        }
    }
}
clickAlert2()
```

```html
<div id="ngList"></div>
```

Comment: Yes sir! That works! I see now what I should have done with the return! Big thanks to everyone!